# How Do I Add Fade Out Images To My Django Page?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am a little new to Django, currently working on a intranet webpage and im trying to add fade out images to add beauty to my design. pls can anyone help me a solution to that?

I also would need help on dynamic images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this has nothing to do with django or python.  it's all javascript

Comment: o yes it does  http://readthedocs.org/projects/django-intranet/

Comment: I think Dmitry's point is that fading out images is typically done with JavaScript (or jQuery), and that JavaScript is not unique to Django or Python. In other words, it's not really a Django or Python question unless you intend to do some image manipulation with the Python Imaging Library, or something along those lines (which does not appear to be your intention).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using Javascript. Easier would be to use [jQuery fadeout api](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).